# Vue: Getting the router instance in children components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vue-router

I'm using Vue.js and vue-router, I'm trying to navigate on a click event.

According to vue-router [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html) I should use the `router.push(name)` API function.

The thing is that the router is initialized in the `App` root component and I want to navigate from one of the `App` component children.

Is there a way to grab the router insatnce from `this.$root` or something similar?

Comment: Well you have to define that child component in the routes, assign it path and name, and then you can do just `router.push('child-component')`.
I'm not sure that I totally understand your issue, so better explanation would help a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the [vue-router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/component-injections.html), every component is being injected with `$router` and `$route` objects, making them accessible via `this.$router` and `this.$route` inside the component.

If you want to navigate from your component javascript code, you just need to do:

```
this.$router.push({path: 'thepath'});
```

If you want to navigate from your template, you can use:

```
<router-link :to="{path: 'thepath'}">The link</router-link>
```

There are examples of usage on the [vue-router repository](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/tree/dev/examples).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a very simple way -- it is [automatically injected](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/component-injections.html) into all child components as `this.$router` if you configured it per instructions in the [official guide](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/getting-started.html#javascript)).

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are using Vue.js 2 ( edited from @jeerbl answer )

```
<router-link :to="{path: 'thepath'}">The link</router-link>
```

Comment: Would be better using `router-link` with the `to` parameter